# is it possible to install dart 2.17 in macOS

Tags: homebrew

Today when I install dart 2.17 in macOS 12.5 using this command:

```
~ ⌚ 18:23:16
$ brew install dart@2.17                                                                                                                       ‹ruby-2.7.2›

Warning: No available formula with the name "dart@2.17". Did you mean dart@2.7, dart@2.1, dart@2.13, dart@2.12, dart@2.10, dart@2.2, dart@2.8, dart@2.6, dart@2.5, dart@2.4, dart@2.3, dart@2.9 or dart@2.0?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.7        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.12       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.8        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.4        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.0
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.1        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.10       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.6        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.3
dart-lang/dart/dart@2.13       dart-lang/dart/dart@2.2        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.5        dart-lang/dart/dart@2.9
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install dart-lang/dart/dart@2.7
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
(base)
```

I check the dart version history from here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution . it contains the dart version 2.17, what should I do to install dart 2.17 in macOS? I have already tried this command:

```
$ brew upgrade dart                                                                                                                            ‹ruby-2.7.2›

Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart 2.14.4 already installed
```

I have already tried running `dart-sdk` like this:

```
~ ⌚ 18:55:01
$ brew install dart-sdk                                                                                                                        ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Warning: No available formula with the name "dart-sdk". Did you mean dartsim?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
This similarly named formula was found:
dartsim
To install it, run:
  brew install dartsim
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No
```

still could not work.

Comment: Try running `brew install dart-sdk`

Comment: this command still could not install the new version of dart. @NimeshNeema

Comment: What is the version of Homebrew that you are running (obtained by running `brew --version`). Have you updated your local cache by running `brew update`?

Comment: Have you tried `brew tap dart-lang/dart` ?